# Upgrade column data type in derby DB

Tags: sql, database, derby, alter

I need to alter my table and change a VARCHAR2 column to be CLOB.
The following script is too slow (8 minutes) for me when having 1 million records:

```
ALTER TABLE SA.EVENT_PARAMS ADD COLUMN NEW_VALUE CLOB(65344);
UPDATE SA.EVENT_PARAMS SET NEW_VALUE=VALUE;
ALTER TABLE SA.EVENT_PARAMS DROP COLUMN VALUE;
RENAME COLUMN SA.EVENT_PARAMS.NEW_VALUE TO VALUE;
```

Is there another way to do this? Talking about apache derby.

Thanks

Comment: Eight minutes doesn't sound that slow. Is this a one-time operation? Or are you anticipating doing it many, many times?

Comment: Yes it's not that slow. This done during the upgrade of the system and for that we are going down. We have a limit for how much time being down and 8 minutes is exceeding that. If there is no other way, maybe drop column can be done asynchronly somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you can have a more sophisticated upgrade process, for example, maybe you can perform this database alteration on a **copy** of the database, (while keeping your application up, but in some sort of "read-only" mode?) and then after the schema changes are complete, you can arrange to "hot swap" your backup database and your primary database, with limited downtime. Another possibility, as you suggest, would be to forego the "drop column" part, and just leave the column there. Have you timed the individual steps in your script?